# alert and prompt javascript

Tags: javascript, alert, prompt

The browser show me "thinksHarry Potter" without space between "thinks" and "harry" words, so my guys can you tell me how can I do that? This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");

        if (person != null) {
          alert("thinks" + person);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `alert('thinks ' + person);`

Comment: This has to be a wind up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's easy man, you have to notice that you have no spaces after the 'thinks' or before 'harry'.

make a space after think:

```
alert('thinks' + person);
```

or before harry:

```
var person=prompt("Please enter your name"," Harry Potter");
```

Comment: you added no space after thinks!

Answer (score 2):

Just put a space after `thinks` in alert message

```
if (person!=null)
  {
    alert('thinks ' + person);
  }
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LBnLE/)

Answer (score 1):

Place a space character inside the first string.

```
alert('thinks ' + person);
```